# Handling session variables in view file in sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am trying to use a session variable in my view file. My controller code is like this

```
User.find()
.where({ username: username })
.where({ password: password })
.exec(function(err, users) {
  if(users.length == 1){
    req.session.user_detail = users; 
    res.redirect('/member');
  }else{
    console.log(err);  
  }
});
```

I want to use the req.session.user_detail in my member.ejs file.

Comment: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/views

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record, in case someone stumbles onto this question instead of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963840/accessing-session-variables-in-sailsjs-view/21976609#21976609), `req.session` is indeed available by default in your Sails views. So you can just do

```
<%= JSON.stringify(req.session.user_detail) %>
```

in your view; there's no need to pass it explicitly in `res.locals`.  You can also loop through the users with:

```
<%  req.session.user_detail.forEach(function(user_detail) { %>
<%=   JSON.stringify(user_detail) %>
<%  }) %>
```

Comment: Your reply was helpful but it just displays [object][object]. I used <%= JSON.stringify(req.session.user_details) %> and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I myself am new to nodejs/sailjs but from what I understand, req.session is not exposed to the views. The way I have been passing data from the session to the views is as follows:

```
res.locals.user_detail= _.clone(req.session.user_detail);
```

You can then access res.locals.user_detail from within your view. I do not know if this is the right way to do it, but this is what I have been using and has worked for me. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just try accessing like that

```
session.user_detail
```