# Accessing session variables in sailsjs view

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ejs

I am quite new to sailsjs and nodejs. I am trying to create an authentication page, wherein once a user is authenticated, I want to set

```
req.session.user = user.id
req.session.authenticated = true
```

I then need to access these values within my main layout.ejs file. I have done so by using

```
res.locals.user = _.clone( req.session.user )
```

However, I noticed that this clone method has to be called in every function of every controller so as to allow me to be able to access the user from within the views. Is there a better way of accessing session variables in sailsjs globbaly, without having to clone the req.session in every controller. An example of what I am doing can be found here:

http://pastebin.com/HyE2H4Kq

As you can see, I have called the clone method at the beginning of various functions within the controller.

Comment: If the user id has been assigned to `req.session.user`, you can reference a variable named `user` in the view file and call `res.view({user: req.session.user})` in the controller action.

Comment: @bnuhero: Thanks for the reply. As stated in my post, this is what I do not want to do. Since the user session details are needed to be accessed from within layout.ejs file, I do not want to pass the user details from within every controller action to the view. Is there any way to access the session details globally, or to set values which can be accessed from within any view, without explicitly being set on every controller action?

Comment: You can define a custom middleware to achieve this. For details, visit  this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267550/what-is-the-proper-way-to-integrate-dynamic-content-into-the-layout-ejs-file-in)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `req` object is available in your views by default, unless you overwrite `res.locals` completely.  So you can access a session variable in your view with `<%=req.session.user%>` (if you're using EJS).  You don't have to copy it explicitly into your locals.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's really useful for stuff like showing the Sign out button

Comment: @Scott Gress: Thanks for the reply, I shall try this tonight and accept if it works for me.

Comment: @Scott Gress: Thank you for your reply. I have upvoted your answer as it is valid, but I have finally gone with the option shown below.

Comment: can we have if else statements in the <%= %> tags?

Comment: @glasspill No, but you can put any Javascript you want in `<% %>` tags (without the `=`).  See the [EJS reference](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone using `passport.js`, session of the user is saved inside `req.session.passport.user` and you also can access it directly from the view

Answer (score -2):

I have finally decided to go with a solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267706/create-config-variables-in-sails-js) as I found this to be the neatest solution.

I have created a config file called userdata.config in which I have the following code:

```
module.exports.userdata = {
    guest: true,
    authenticated: false
};
```

I am then accessing this in the controller as follows:

```
sails.config.userdata.authenticated = true;
sails.config.userdata.guest = false;
sails.config.userdata.user = sessionUser;
```

This is then accessed in the view as follows:

```
sails.config.userdata.user.firstName
```

Comment: you know that sails.config.userdata will be shared among all requests if it was not cleared?

Comment: Yes.  Sails configuration is global across *all requests*, not a single request or session.  This is not a good solution unless you only plan on supporting one logged-in user at a time.

Comment: @sgress454 What is your suggestion instead of doing this but with out using `req.session`? Because I'm using JWT authentication, so I don't have session storage. In every request I receive the token and in the payload it has the user ID so how can I make globally accessed that info for every request?